# How to limit characters in TextBox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a button1 whose text is 0, the times i click on button the button text will appear in textbox the code is mention below :

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox8.Text = TextBox8.Text + "0"
        End Sub
```

**My problem :**

i want to limit the characters print in the textbox after clicking the button1.

I want if my textbox maximum length in 2 then after 2 charcters i click on button it will not print the text of button1 after two characters.

Comment: So you want to disable the button on clientside when the  `MaxLength` property of the TextBox is reached?

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't exactly understand your problem, are you trying to limit the maximum number of charcters that can appear in textbox or something else? If it is so, so can set the MaxLength property of textbox.

Comment: What you want in which technology you want to do it using code behind(.net) or jquery??

Answer (score 1):

You may try **setting MaxLength** and use it to check if current text length has reached maximum

```
' code behind
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox8.Text.Length < TextBox8.MaxLength Then
        TextBox8.Text = TextBox8.Text & "0"
    End If
End Sub

' aspx page
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" MaxLength="2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
```

If you could be a little bit more precise what you try to achieve, I could adapt my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to follow, but are you looking for the TextBox.MaxLength property?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx

Or, you could just check the length in code:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If TextBox8.Text.Length < 3 Then TextBox8.Text = TextBox8.Text + "0"
End Sub
```